# Why older versions of Webview Android are not passing the cookies for CORS requests?

Tags: cordova, webview, android-webview

I'm implementing a cordova app, and I'm struggling with maintaining a session with a 3rd party API.

The 3rd party API accepts CORS connection.
I am able to log in and obtain a session cookie, but Webview fails to pass that cookie, on subsequent requests to the API. This problem seem to occur only on older versions: eg I see it while testing on Android 7 and 8. With Android 13, the problem goes away (with no changes on the server or client side).

Any idea how I can force the older webview instances to pass the CORS cookies?

My cordova version:

```
cordova --version
12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
```

My cordova config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>
    <author email="admin@test.com" href="https://www.test.com">
        test
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <preference name="scheme" value="https" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="www.myRemoteAPI.com"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="25" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />
    <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="33" />
    <icon src="./www/p/img/logoCirclet.png" />
    
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

The login response headers look like this:

```
Server: nginx/1.22.1
Date: Tue, 23 May 2023 14:18:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
set-cookie: _session=VEn26fd1uEKHFeSBZU4nw6dbYQXZrLSyTo6PGFbq8Q+jIIDKtmC5JX7A3yv+k9YErp2yWcmYKHPJXfLt+QYq2Sgu2RFYzXriBSK8ac/h11PPw; Max-Age=604800; Expires=Tue, 30 May 2023 14:18:05 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 75
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.myRemoteAPI.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-expose-headers: _session
```

The subsequent requests headers, look like this :

```
GET /k/usersfriends?limit=7&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myRemoteAPI.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Android SDK built for x86 Build/NYC; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 1541fbf1-302d-41a2-b5f1-5d48cfc25864
Accept: */*
Referer: https://www.myRemoteAPI.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
X-Requested-With: com.test
```

As you can see, the _session cookie is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a solution: What I've did was to pass the fetch option credentials, as follows:

```
 let settings = {
        method: 'GET'
    };
  settings["credentials"] = 'same-origin';

  let response = await fetch(url, settings);
```